# Zero Hashes Per Second with Diablo-D3 Miner

Tags: miner-configuration, hashpower, gpu-mining, diablominer

I'm trying to setup Diablo-D3 Miner on my computer (I'm aware that there are other solutions available, but I need something written in Java for a personal project) and I see in console I'm getting zero hashes:

```
mh: 0.0/0.0 | a/r/hwe: 0/0/0 | gh: 0.0 0.0 | fps: Infinity
```

Why is my hash rate zero when I have NVIDIA CUDA OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 9.1.75 and   GeForce GTX 960M installed on my system and it's being detected by Diablo?

Thanks in advance.